# Getting error while creating the tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following SQL script:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE part
> (Partno    CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
>  Partdesc  VARCHAR(20),
>  Onhand    INTEGER,
>  Partclass CHAR(2) check (Partclass IN ('AP','HW','KI','SP')),
>  Unitprice DECIMAL(6,2)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE salesrep
> (Srepno     CHAR(3),
>  Srepname   VARCHAR(25),
>  Srepstreet VARCHAR(30),
>  Srepcity   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
>  Srepprov   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
>  Sreppcode  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
>  Totcomm    DECIMAL(8,2),
>  Commrate   DECIMAL(3,2),
>  CONSTRAINT pkslsrep PRIMARY KEY (Srepno)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE customer
> (Custno     CHAR(3),
>  Custname   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
>  Custstreet VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>  Custcity   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
>  Custprov   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
>  Custpcode  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
>  Disc       DECIMAL(3,1),
>  Balance    DECIMAL(7,2),
>  Credlimit  DECIMAL(5),
>  Srepno     CHAR(3),
>  CONSTRAINT pkcustno PRIMARY KEY (Custno),
>  CONSTRAINT fksrepno FOREIGN KEY (Srepno) REFERENCES salesrep(Srepno)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE orders
> (Orderno   CHAR(5) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
>  Orderdate DATE,
>  Custno    CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
>  CONSTRAINT fkordercust FOREIGN KEY (Custno) REFERENCES customer (Custno)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE orderprod
> (Orderno    CHAR(5),
>  Partno     CHAR(4),
>  Orderqty   INTEGER CHECK (Orderqty>0),
>  Orderprice DECIMAL(7,2),
>  CONSTRAINT pkorderprod PRIMARY KEY (Orderno, Partno),
>  CONSTRAINT fkordprdord FOREIGN KEY (Orderno) REFERENCES orders(Orderno),
>  CONSTRAINT fkordprdpar FOREIGN KEY (Partno) REFERENCES part(Partno)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE invoice
> ( Invno     CHAR(6),
>   Invdate   DATE,
>   Orderno    CHAR(5),
>   CONSTRAINT fkinvoice FOREIGN KEY (Orderno) REFERENCES orders(Orderno),
>   CONSTRAINT pkinvoice PRIMARY KEY (Invno)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE invprod
> ( Invno     CHAR(6),
>   Partno     CHAR(4),
>   Shipqty    INTEGER CHECK (Shipqty>0),
>   CONSTRAINT fkinvoice FOREIGN KEY (Invno) REFERENCES invoice(Invno),
>   CONSTRAINT fkpart FOREIGN KEY (Partno) REFERENCES part(Partno)
> );
>
> DROP TABLE invprod;
> DROP TABLE invoice;
> DROP TABLE orderprod;
> DROP TABLE orders;
> DROP TABLE customer;
> DROP TABLE salesrep;
> DROP TABLE part;*
> ```

I am not able to create the table invprod. I am getting the error: 69 Can't create table 'sh.invprod' (errno: 121). What errors am I making in this script?

Comment: If you do a `show innodb status`, buried in the middle of the output will be a more detailed "last error" section, which should have a better explanation of why you can't create the table.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I've just tried it on 5.1.57 and it worked fine

Comment: your script works fine for me, other than having to delete the '*' at the end.  What version of SQLite are you using?

Answer (score 2):

`CONSTRAINT fkinvoice` is already defined as part of `CREATE TABLE invoice`. Constraint names should be unique like tables or indexes.

Comment: -1: key names are per-table. having `fkinvoice` in one table does not prevent you from having the same key name in another table.

Comment: @Marc B: If the `CONSTRAINT symbol` clause is given, the `symbol` value must be unique in the database. Refer to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Well, ain't that just peachy. Oracle really should make those docs easier to read. If you'd care to do any kind of edit to your question, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @Raihan I just changed the foreign key name, but now it's not creating the tables..:(

Comment: @Raihan It's not doing anything..:/